# Camel , catch error and move file in different folder

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to doing ETL job (read,convert, store an excel) .
This route work fine :

```
from("file:src/data?move=processed&moveFailed=error&idempotent=true")
            .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
          .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList");
```

but I need a customization in case of Exception : I need to move file in other folder , then applied :

```
onException(Throwable.class).maximumRedeliveries(0).to("file:src/data?move=error");
```

But file component can't move the file because is locket by first file comp instance.
Then I am tryinf to use try/catch but it doesn't work (probably the move operation inside catch is unaware of correct file name ? )

```
from("file:src/data?noop=true")
        .doTry()
            .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
            .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")
            .to("file:src/data?move=processed")
        .doCatch(Throwable.class)
            .to("file:src/data?move=error")
        .end();
```

tanks

After many comments my current code looks like :

```
from("file:src/data?noop=false&delete=true")
        .doTry()
            .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")                  .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")
            .to("file:src/data/processed")
        .doCatch(Throwable.class)
            .to("file:src/data/error")
            /*
            .doFinally()
                .to("file:src/data:delete=true")
            */
        .end();
```

It move correctly the file in processed and error folder but the file remain in main folder and is preocessed more ,recursively

Comment: In your second code, set noop=false. When set to true it won't delete or move the file.

Comment: Also, add a file name in your second .to(). You can add the filename from your original from() in a header and use that in your second to.

Comment: "second code" you mean onException(......  ?   Ho I can put fileName and read late it from Header ?   thanks

Comment: from("file:src/data?noop=true")
        .doTry() , here set noop=false

Comment: Yes, set fileName in a header or exchange property and use it in your .to() when you want to move the file.

Comment: sorry but I dosn't know how to get file name , can you show me how to get it and put inside header  ?

Comment: Can provide you code in an hour or so..

Comment: Did the hint work? Setting noop=false.

Comment: No , the file is processed one time and not moved , then re processed recursively , I need an example showing how to get fileName from file component and put it in Header properties .  Still , there is a way to avoid multiple processing ? I tryed "onException(Throwable.class).maximumRedeliveries(0)" but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well then you need remove the `idempotent=true` from the parameters, then it should work:

```
from("file:src/data?move=processed&moveFailed=error")
          .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
          .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList");
```

The previous route moves the file to the `processed` folder if the routing was successful otherwise it moves the file to the `error` folder (if any exception happens). The filename won't be changed.

### Other solution with try-catch

```
from("file://src/data?delete=true")
        .doTry()
            .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
            .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")
            .to("file://src/data/processed")
        .doCatch(Throwable.class)
            .to("file://src/data/error")
        .end();
```

Comment: No, already tried . moveFailed option refer to error on initial move

Comment: What do you mean by "initial move"? Would you like to handle one specific exception or any exception during the routing? Do you have an onException() specified in your route?

Comment: moveFailed take place only if fire an exception on moving the file , this as reported in file2 component documentation

Comment: Not exactly, it `used to dynamically set a different target directory when moving files in case of processing (configured via move defined above) failed.` (http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) So, it moves the file to the specified folder if any exception happens during the processing (for example when your `ExcelTransformer.process` class throws an exception).  And it moves the file to the `processed` folder if everything was successful. Do you want to achieve the previous or other thing?

Comment: Updated my answer with an other solution which uses doTry(), doCatch().

Comment: I need just what you wrote , peocess excel file and if no erro ,archive it in processed folder , if error happen archive it in error folder . Maybe the correct behavior of moveFailed is as you understood ,but the code below doesn't work and camel get error but continue to process recursively the file ,any move   

        
        from("file:src/data?move=processed&moveFailed=error")
            .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
          .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList");

Comment: Have you tried the other solution I posted? Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Is the same solution I already tried but no move take place , I need to specify a fileName in second file component I think , look at the initial post to see my solution is the same than yours

Comment: It's not the same, but I'm pretty sure that you don't need to specify the filename if you would like to use the same as your source file, because that header ("CamelFileName") is already specified by the file consumer (from("file:...")). What's the problem exactly with it? (I have tried with almost the same solution and it works on my side)

Comment: `move` and `moveFailed` can be used only on a file consumer.

Comment: then not correct to use moveFailed as parameter on from command ?

Comment: Nope, it's correct to use the `moveFailed` as the file parameter in the `from()`. The consumer is specified by the `from()`, but you used the `move` parameter in your producer (`to("file:..")`).
Have you really tried what I posted (the doTry()-doCatch() solution)? What's the problem with it?

Comment: it seems work now , on error the file is moved on error folder but I need to delete it form main folder in finally clause

Comment: Delete the `noop=true` parameter from the `from()`.

Comment: if I delet noop=true camel move the file in .camel folder

Comment: Add `delete=true` to the file consumer.

Comment: yes    from("file:src/data?noop=false&delete=true")  but don't work

Comment: any other suggestion ?

Comment: What's missing exactly? With the `delete=true` it should delete the file after processing and you don't need the `noop` setting.

Comment: yes , I am not able to delete file and camel continue to elaborate it : this is my route :         from("file:src/data?noop=false&delete=true")
            .doTry()
                .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
                .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")
                .to("file:src/data/processed")
                .log("TRY...............")
            .doCatch(Throwable.class)
                .to("file:src/data/error").log("CATCH ............")
            .end();

Comment: Try to remove the noop=false parameter as I had mentioned before: `from("file:src/data?delete=true")`

Comment: I am doing as follow but the file isn't moved and not deleted :    from("file:src/data?noop=false&delete=true")
            .doTry()
                .bean(ExcelTransformer.class,"process")
                .to("jpa:cie.service.receiver.DatiTelefonici?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")
                .to("file:src/data/processed")
                .log("TRY...............")